# Как запринтить массив со словарями не в строку?

Tags: python

Если есть большой массив, то читать его в строку не удобно, при этом там есть словари, у них подсловари могут быть, как сделать нечто подобное принтом для удобности?

```
{
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "value": "ООО \"МОТОРИКА\"",
      "unrestricted_value": "ООО \"МОТОРИКА\"",
      "data": {
        "kpp": "773101001",
        "capital": { "type": "УСТАВНЫЙ КАПИТАЛ", "value": 51348.0 },
        "management": {
          "name": "Чех Илья Игоревич",
          "post": "ГЕНЕРАЛЬНЫЙ ДИРЕКТОР",
          "disqualified": null
        },
        "founders": [
          {
            "ogrn": null,
            "inn": null,
            "name": "КОМПАНИЯ ХОМО АУКТУС ЛИМИТЕД",
            "hid": "cada330cd8bdf8362b7653bc0b45cd743bbd3ff344b32f7b898c4b8d144a7fd4",
            "type": "LEGAL",
            "share": { "value": 77.8998, "type": "PERCENT" }
          },
          {
            "ogrn": "1187746709358",
            "inn": "7728437776",
            "name": "ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ \"УК ДАЛЬНЕВОСТОЧНЫЙ ФОНД ВЫСОКИХ ТЕХНОЛОГИЙ\"",
            "hid": "0ff0c9392d0b91c58559633b37531cfcc9555563b3aee8ca20ad5e6c987896f2",
            "type": "LEGAL",
            "share": { "value": 22.1002, "type": "PERCENT" }
          }
        ],
        "managers": [
            {
              "inn": "781303761704",
              "fio": {
                "surname": "Чех",
                "name": "Илья",
                "patronymic": "Игоревич",
                "gender": "MALE",
                "source": "ЧЕХ ИЛЬЯ ИГОРЕВИЧ",
                "qc": null
              },
              "post": "ГЕНЕРАЛЬНЫЙ ДИРЕКТОР",
              "hid": "e680692ab083c142ceee2a09e57529c6d740c95c5216520a35d325c9edbcad64",
              "type": "EMPLOYEE"
            }
        ],
        "predecessors": null,
        "successors": null,
        "branch_type": "MAIN",
        "branch_count": 0,
        "source": null,
        "qc": null,
        "hid": "baf582914d601bc5246e881b07dfa6e336091a3857bebc3bf389aa0b4073223c",
        "type": "LEGAL",
        "state": {
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "code": null,
          "actuality_date": 1611273600000,
          "registration_date": 1423094400000,
          "liquidation_date": null
        },
        "opf": {
          "type": "2014",
          "code": "12300",
          "full": "Общество с ограниченной ответственностью",
          "short": "ООО"
        },
        "name": {
          "full_with_opf": "ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ \"МОТОРИКА\"",
          "short_with_opf": "ООО \"МОТОРИКА\"",
          "latin": null,
          "full": "МОТОРИКА",
          "short": "МОТОРИКА"
        },
        "inn": "7719402047",
        "ogrn": "1157746078984",
        "okpo": "27539247",
        "okato": "45268569000",
        "oktmo": "45321000000",
        "okogu": "4210011",
        "okfs": "34",
        "okved": "72.19",
        "okveds": [
          {
            "main": true,
            "type": "2014",
            "code": "72.19",
            "name": "Научные исследования и разработки в области естественных и технических наук прочие"
          }
        ],
        "authorities": {
          "fts_registration": {
            "type": "FEDERAL_TAX_SERVICE",
            "code": "7746",
            "name": "Межрайонная инспекция Федеральной налоговой службы № 46 по г. Москве",
            "address": "125373, г.Москва, Походный проезд, домовладение 3, стр.2"
          },
          "fts_report": {
            "type": "FEDERAL_TAX_SERVICE",
            "code": "7731",
            "name": "Инспекция Федеральной налоговой службы № 31 по г.Москве",
            "address": null
          },
          "pf": {
            "type": "PENSION_FUND",
            "code": "087803",
            "name": "Государственное учреждение - Главное Управление Пенсионного фонда РФ №2 Управление №7 по г. Москве и Московской области муниципальный район Можайский г.Москвы",
            "address": null
          },
          "sif": {
            "type": "SOCIAL_INSURANCE_FUND",
            "code": "7738",
            "name": "Филиал №38 Государственного учреждения - Московского регионального отделения Фонда социального страхования Российской Федерации",
            "address": null
          }
        },
        "documents": {
          "fts_registration": {
            "type": "FTS_REGISTRATION",
            "series": "77",
            "number": "016942308",
            "issue_date": 1423094400000,
            "issue_authority": "7746"
          },
          "fts_report": {
            "type": "FTS_REPORT",
            "series": null,
            "number": null,
            "issue_date": 1519084800000,
            "issue_authority": "7731"
          },
          "pf_registration": {
            "type": "PF_REGISTRATION",
            "series": null,
            "number": "087803025754",
            "issue_date": 1519689600000,
            "issue_authority": "087803"
          },
          "sif_registration": {
            "type": "SIF_REGISTRATION",
            "series": null,
            "number": "772406613777381",
            "issue_date": 1512432000000,
            "issue_authority": "7738"
          },
          "smb": {
            "category": "SMALL",
            "type": "SMB",
            "series": null,
            "number": null,
            "issue_date": 1565384400000,
            "issue_authority": null
          }
        },
        "licenses": null,
        "finance": {
          "tax_system": null,
          "income": 90183000.0,
          "expense": 128338000.0,
          "debt": null,
          "penalty": null,
          "year": 2019
        },
        "address": {
          "value": "121205, ГОРОД МОСКВА, ТЕРРИТОРИЯ СКОЛКОВО ИННОВАЦИОННОГО ЦЕНТРА, БУЛЬВАР БОЛЬШОЙ, ДОМ 42, СТРОЕНИЕ 1, ЭТ 1 ПОМ 334 РАБ 10",
          "unrestricted_value": "121205, ГОРОД МОСКВА, ТЕРРИТОРИЯ СКОЛКОВО ИННОВАЦИОННОГО ЦЕНТРА, БУЛЬВАР БОЛЬШОЙ, ДОМ 42, СТРОЕНИЕ 1, ЭТ 1 ПОМ 334 РАБ 10",
          "data": {...}
        },
        "phones": [
          {
            "value": "+7 911 2410309",
            "unrestricted_value": "+7 911 2410309",
            "data": {
                "contact": null,
                "source": "+7 911 241 0309",
                "qc": null,
                "type": "Мобильный",
                "number": "2410309",
                "extension": null,
                "provider": "ПАО \"Мобильные ТелеСистемы\"",
                "country": null,
                "region": "Санкт-Петербург и Ленинградская область",
                "city": null,
                "timezone": "UTC+3",
                "country_code": "7",
                "city_code": "911",
                "qc_conflict": null
            }
          }
        ],
        "emails": [
          {
            "value": "INFO@MOTORICA.ORG",
            "unrestricted_value": "INFO@MOTORICA.ORG",
            "data": {
              "local": "INFO",
              "domain": "MOTORICA.ORG",
              "type": null,
              "source": "info@motorica.org",
              "qc": null
            }
          }
        ],
        "ogrn_date": 1423094400000,
        "okved_type": "2014",
        "employee_count": 59
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Стандартная библиотека *Data pretty printer*, например https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать модуль `json`.

```
weapon_skins = {
    "knifes": [
        "Falchion – Blued steel",
        "Bowie Knife – Damascus Steel",
        "Stiletto – Surface hardening"
    ],
    "pistols": [
        "USP-S | Conductor",
        "Glock-18 | Moonlit Night"
    ]
}

from json import dumps
print(dumps(weapon_skins, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```